# Passing Php string to AngularJS gives parse error

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

If I pass a php string to Angular JS, it gives me the following error:

Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 54-54 [#] in expression

I am trying to pass the string into angular to show a dialog:

```
<md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showAlert($event, '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($list['Shipment']['notes']) ;?>', 'Notes')" flex="" flex-md="100" md-theme="cyan">
```

Is there any way to get around this error?

Comment: `'<?php echo htmlspecialchars($list['Shipment']['notes']) ;?>'` to `"<?php echo htmlspecialchars($list['Shipment']['notes']) ;?>"` you are ending the string at `'Shipment'`

Comment: `<?php $desc = $item["OfferItem"]["description"] ; $nme = $item["OfferItem"]["name"]; ?>
                <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showAlert($event, '<?php echo $desc; ?>', 'Description for ' + '<?php echo $nme; ?>')" flex="" flex-md="100" >`

even with this code it is giving me the error : 
Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 398-400 [')] in expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to prefix the string with the php function addslashes()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

Not very nice what you want, but do this:

```
<?= '<md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showAlert($event, \'' . htmlspecialchars($list['Shipment']['notes']) . '\', \'Notes\')" flex="" flex-md="100" md-theme="cyan">'; ?>
```

Comment: $event is from angularjs, not?

Comment: Correct. But the solution was to prefix the string with the php function addslashes().